# React usestate updates twice when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a dropdown that appears when a button is clicked inside of react table.

```
  function Table({ columns, data, getTrProps, isShowing }) {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  const currentColOrder = React.useRef();
  const { store } = useContext(AppContext);

  const handleChange = () => {
    setIsVisible(() => !isVisible);
  };

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    allColumns,
    visibleColumns,
    setColumnOrder,
    getToggleHideAllColumnsProps,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
    },
    useSortBy,
    useRowSelect,
    useColumnOrder,

    hooks => {
      hooks.visibleColumns.push(columns => [
        {
          id: 'selection',
          className: 'selection',
          disableSortBy: true,
          accessor: '',

          Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),

          Cell: ({ row }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
        },
        ...columns,
        {
          className: 'Columns_Menu',
          disableSortBy: true,
          id: 'Eye',
          Header: () => (
            <StyledEyeButton type="button" onClick={handleChange} id="eye">
              <Eye />
            </StyledEyeButton>
          ),

          Cell: () => <div />,
        },
      ]);
    },
  );

  return (
    <>
      <StyledTable {...getTableProps()} isShowing={isShowing}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <DragDropContext
              onDragStart={() => {
                currentColOrder.current = visibleColumns.map(o => o.id);
              }}
              onDragUpdate={dragUpdateObj => {
                const colOrder = [...currentColOrder.current];
                const sIndex = dragUpdateObj.source.index;
                const dIndex = dragUpdateObj.destination && dragUpdateObj.destination.index;

                if (typeof sIndex === 'number' && typeof dIndex === 'number') {
                  colOrder.splice(sIndex, 1);
                  colOrder.splice(dIndex, 0, dragUpdateObj.draggableId);
                  setColumnOrder(colOrder);
                }
              }}
              key={1}
            >
              <Droppable droppableId="droppable" direction="horizontal">
                {droppableProvided => (
                  <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()} ref={droppableProvided.innerRef}>
                    {headerGroup.headers.map((column, index) => (
                      <Draggable
                        key={column.id}
                        draggableId={column.id}
                        index={index}
                        isDragDisabled={!column.accessor}
                      >
                        {(provided, snapshot) => {
                          return (
                            <StyledTh {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                              <div {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                                <div
                                  {...provided.draggableProps}
                                  {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                  ref={provided.innerRef}
                                  style={{
                                    ...getItemStyle(snapshot, provided.draggableProps.style),
                                  }}
                                >
                                  <StyledHeader className="header">
                                    {column.render('Header')}
                                    {column.id === 'selection' || column.id === 'Eye' ? (
                                      ''
                                    ) : column.isSorted ? (
                                      column.isSortedDesc ? (
                                        <UpChevron />
                                      ) : (
                                        <DownChevron />
                                      )
                                    ) : (
                                      <DownChevron />
                                    )}
                                  </StyledHeader>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </StyledTh>
                          );
                        }}
                      </Draggable>
                    ))}
                  </tr>
                )}
              </Droppable>
            </DragDropContext>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row);

            return (
              <StyledTr {...row.getRowProps()} data-testid="row">
                {store?.get?.isLoadingSearchButton || store?.get?.isLoadingApplyButton
                  ? row.cells.map(cell => {
                      return (
                        <StyledTd
                          {...cell.getCellProps()}
                          {...getTrProps(cell)}
                          className={cell.column.className}
                        >
                          <Skeleton width="50%" />
                        </StyledTd>
                      );
                    })
                  : row.cells.map(cell => {
                      return (
                        <StyledTd
                          {...cell.getCellProps()}
                          {...getTrProps(cell)}
                          className={cell.column.className}
                        >
                          {cell.render('Cell')}
                        </StyledTd>
                      );
                    })}
              </StyledTr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </StyledTable>
      {isVisible ? (
        <DropDownTableMenu
          setIsVisible={setIsVisible}
          allColumns={allColumns}
          getToggleHideAllColumnsProps={getToggleHideAllColumnsProps}
          isVisible={isVisible}
        />
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

The value `isVisible` is initially false. When I click the `StyledEyeButton` the dropdown opens like it should and the `isVisible` value is changed to true.

However when I click the button again to close the dropdown the value for `isVisible` switches to false and then switches a second time back to true so the dropdown never closes.

I have an on outside click function that is passed down to the dropdown in the table and when you click outside the dropdown it closes fine, but it's just when you try to click the eye button to close the dropdown after opening that the problem arises.

I thought that using an anonymous function in the `handleChange` was supposed to fix the problem, but it doesn't. Any ideas what's causing this? The only thing I can think of is because the button itself is being rendered from a function and this is causing a state issue, but I wasn't sure because the button shouldn't be re-rendered after initial load.

Comment: Would you share your full code?

Currently, I can't find any usage of isVisible in your code.

Comment: Yup there is the whole table function the show dropdown is at the bottom of the function @fi

Comment: It's probably the outside click that causes the problem. When you click on the dropdown, it triggers both - the dropdown click and the outside click. You can solve it by using the`stopPropagation` method.

Comment: I tried removing the OutsideClickHandler component that wraps the dropdown component and that didn't fix it either @yochanansheinberger

Comment: what does your outside click look like? I think the problem is in your outside click